# Git: Merge a Remote branch locally

Tags: git, repository, branch, git-branch

I've pulled all remote branches via `git fetch --all`. I can see the branch I'd like to merge via `git branch -a` as remotes/origin/branchname. Problem is it is not accessible. I can't merge or checkout.

Answer (score 509, accepted):

You can reference those remote tracking branches ~(listed with `git branch -r`) with the name of their remote.

You need to fetch the remote branch:

```
git fetch origin aRemoteBranch
```

If you want to merge one of those remote branches on your local branch:

```
git checkout aLocalBranch
git merge origin/aRemoteBranch
```

*Note 1:* For a large repo with a long history, you will want to add the `--depth=1` option when you use `git fetch`.

*Note 2:* These commands also work with other remote repos so you can setup an `origin` and an `upstream` if you are working on a fork.

*Note 3*: [user3265569](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265569/user3265569) suggests the following alias [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651185/git-merge-a-remote-branch-locally/21653559#comment116902338_21653559):

> From `aLocalBranch`, run `git combine remoteBranch`
> Alias:
>
> ```
> combine = !git fetch origin ${1} && git merge origin/${1}
> ```

---

Opposite scenario: If you want to merge one of your local branch on a remote branch (as opposed to a remote branch to a local one, as shown above), you need to create a *new* local branch on top of said remote branch first:

```
git checkout -b myBranch origin/aBranch
git merge anotherLocalBranch
```

The idea here, is to merge "one of your local branch" (here `anotherLocalBranch`) to a remote branch (`origin/aBranch`).
For that, you create first "`myBranch`" as representing that remote branch: that is the `git checkout -b myBranch origin/aBranch` part.
And *then* you can merge `anotherLocalBranch` to it (to `myBranch`).

Comment: aLocalBranch? is that a typo? I guess you meant to write "myBranch" again?

Comment: @knocte No: "If you want to merge one of your local branch on one of those remote branch": I am merging "`aLocalBranch`" to "`myBranch`", with "`myBranch`" representing a remote branch `origin/aBranch`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you @VonC, in your previous comment you say `aLocalBranch` is not a typo, but you approved the latest edit (2 years later!) which corrects this "probable typo". I wanted to check with you before undoing the edit.

Comment: @rath You are correct: it appears I might have reviewed that edit a bit hastily, bordering on carelessness. I did edit the answer to clarify the second merge case: can you tell me if this is clearer now?

Comment: I've created an alias for this. From `aLocalBranch ` run `git combine remoteBranch`. Alias: `combine = !git fetch origin ${1} && git merge origin/${1}`

Comment: @user3265569 Thank you for this contribution. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: As previous comments highlight, this answer overcomplicates the issue with hard to understand branch names and a follow-on answer that isn't in the question. I'm just looking for `git merge remoteMain into featureLocal` or whichever way around it is.

Comment: @RinandLen OK. Did you find a clear answer below?

Answer (score 117):

Whenever I do a merge, I get into the branch I want to merge into (e.g. "`git checkout branch-i-am-working-in`") and then do the following:

`git merge origin/branch-i-want-to-merge-from`

Comment: I guess you have to do a `git fetch origin/branch-i-want-to-merge-from` first, right?

Comment: `git fetch origin develop` followed by `git merge origin/develop`

Comment: @Olivier You are correct, this is the right way to do it. `git merge ` alone won't do it.

Comment: thank you for the clever naming convention which helped me understand

Comment: @Michael Dautermann How can I update the remote after locally merge?

Comment: @Akira Isn't `git add .` -> `git commit -m <message>` -> `git push -u origin <branch>`?

Comment: @CloudCho It's wasn't working before. Now working. Thank you.

Comment: @Olivier, Does the  fetch required? Does ‘git merge origin/remote_branch_name’ reads from remote branch, not local? So I shouldn’t care about fetch

Answer (score 59):

Fetch the remote branch from the origin first.

```
git fetch origin remote_branch_name
```

Merge the remote branch to the local branch

```
git merge origin/remote_branch_name
```

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer reported Not something we can merge. In my case I was merging from another user’s fork of my repo on GitHub.

Comment: Does the first command fetch required? Does ‘git merge origin/remote_branch_name’ reads from remote branch, not local. So I shouldn’t care, is local branch updated or not?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim You do need to fetch first so your local repository knows the state of remote. Git pull is basically a fetch and merge from the current remote version of your current branch, but now you fetch and merge from a different one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Answer (score 24):

Maybe you want to *track* the remote branch with a local branch:

1. Create a new local branch:

```
  git branch -b new-local-branch
```

2. Set this newly created branch to track the remote branch:

```
  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/remote-branch new-local-branch
```

3. Enter into this branch:

```
  git checkout new-local-branch
```

4. Pull all the contents of the remote branch into the local branch:

```
  git pull
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already fetched your remote branch and do `git branch -a`,
you obtain something like :

```
* 8.0
  xxx
  remotes/origin/xxx
  remotes/origin/8.0
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/8.0
  remotes/rep_mirror/8.0
```

After that, you can use `rep_mirror/8.0` to designate locally your remote branch.

The trick is that `remotes/rep_mirror/8.0` doesn't work but `rep_mirror/8.0` does.

So, a command like `git merge -m "my msg" rep_mirror/8.0` do the merge.

(note : this is a comment to @VonC answer. I put it as another answer because code blocks don't fit into the comment format)