# Adding commits from a remote

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote

There are two repositories, both started from one place. Now both have slightly diverged. A already has an `origin` remote. B is on some different remote, let's say `origin2`.

`A: (last common commit)--------------------> A1 -> A2` (28 commits in total)

`B: (last common commit) -> B1 -> B2 -> B3` (29 commits in total)

How do I take B1, B2 and B3 into A? In other words

`Desired: A: (last common commit) -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> A1 -> A2` (31 commits in total)

Ideally I'd like to keep the hashes and commit-names of the B's.

Comment: "Both started from one place" seems in contradiction with the fact they have different origins. When a repo is created by cloning, `origin` is the source of the cloning process. So do you mean they are cloned from the same logical repo, but different servers/machines?

Comment: If master is on a: (`git ckeckout master`) `git merge origin2/master`

Comment: @dan1st `merge: orign2 - not something we can merge`

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh not `origin2` but `origin2/master` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651185/git-merge-a-remote-branch-locally)

Comment: @dan1st `merge: origin2/master - not something we can merge` unfortunately.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: @dan1st nvm i solved it by using `git rebase -i origin2/master`