# How to see a remote branch, created with ADO, locally with a git command?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

I've tried several git commands, but I can't seem to be able to see the remote branch that I've created using azure devops. Branch name is *pbi7642_task7917*.

With
`git branch -av | Select-String task7917`
, on my machine, in powershell, I don't see the new branch.

Comment: Did you fetch already?

Comment: Afterwards, yes.     I did a ```git fetch --all``` and that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch --all` did most of the trick.

Subsequently `git checkout remotes/origin/pbi7642_task7917` and `git switch -c pbi7642_task7917` got me going.

I was helped by similar question *[Git: Merge a Remote branch locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651185/git-merge-a-remote-branch-locally)*.