# Gitlab how to pull down current code on master to the local branch

Tags: gitlab

How does one get the code from the **master** to the **local branch** called "mybranch" so the **local branch** has the latest code? Assume local branch did not have code changed since it was created from master and now it is few versions behind the master.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran the following commands, which pulled the latest changes from master.

> git checkout mybranch
>
> git pull origin master

Answer (score 0):

checkout to your branch:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

then update master and rebase your branch.

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

this is in case you don't mind rebasing and also updating master.
You could also not rebase (say, if mybranch is in the remote and you don't want to remove it to be able to push later) and just merge with

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Please explain what you did, avoid only code answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Assuming that you are on your local branch.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200614/how-to-merge-remote-master-to-local-branch)